# ElasticSearch 5.x Context Suggester NEST .Net

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to create an Index with a context suggester with Nest 5.0 on ElasticSearch 5.1.2.

Currently, I can create the mapping:

```
elasticClient.MapAsync<EO_CategoryAutocomplete>(m => m
                .Properties(p => p
                    .Completion(c => c
                        .Contexts(ctx => ctx
                            .Category(csug => csug
                                .Name("lang")
                                .Path("l")
                            )
                            .Category(csug => csug
                                .Name("type")
                                .Path("t")
                            )
                            .Category(csug => csug
                                .Name("home")
                                .Path("h")
                            )
                        )
                        .Name(n => n.Suggest)
                    )
                )
            );
```

But in the POCO class i dont know what object type must be *Suggest* Property marked with *?????*:

```
public class EO_CategoryAutocomplete
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public ????? Suggest { get; set; }
}

public class EO_CategoryAC
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In NEST 5.0 *CompletionField* Property has been removed (That was the method to do context suggester on elasticsearch 2.X)

Please, can anyone provide an example about how to do it?

The documentation is all about querying. [Suggester NEST](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/suggest-usage.html)

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Completion and Context Suggester are able to return the `_source` in the response in 5.x+, so no longer require a payload. Because of this, the type in NEST 5.x is now `CompletionField`, as opposed to `CompletionField<TPayload>` in NEST 2.x, where `TPayload` is the payload type.

Here's an example with NEST 5.x to get you up and running

```
public class EO_CategoryAutocomplete
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> L { get; set; }
    public CompletionField Suggest { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
            .DefaultIndex("autocomplete");

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    if (client.IndexExists("autocomplete").Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex("autocomplete");

    client.CreateIndex("autocomplete", ci => ci
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<EO_CategoryAutocomplete>(mm => mm
                .AutoMap()
                .Properties(p => p
                    .Completion(c => c
                        .Contexts(ctx => ctx
                            .Category(csug => csug
                                .Name("lang")
                                .Path("l")
                            )
                            .Category(csug => csug
                                .Name("type")
                                .Path("t")
                            )
                            .Category(csug => csug
                                .Name("home")
                                .Path("h")
                            )
                        )
                        .Name(n => n.Suggest)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    client.IndexMany(new[] {
        new EO_CategoryAutocomplete 
        {
            Id = "1",
            Suggest = new CompletionField
            {
                Input = new [] { "async", "await" },
                // explicitly pass a context for lang
                Contexts = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                    { "lang", new [] { "c#" } }
                }
            }
        },
        new EO_CategoryAutocomplete
        {
            Id = "2",
            Suggest = new CompletionField
            {
                Input = new [] { "async", "await" },
                // explicitly pass a context for lang
                Contexts = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                    { "lang", new [] { "javascript" } }
                }
            }
        },
        new EO_CategoryAutocomplete
        {
            Id = "3",
            // let completion field mapping extract lang from the path l
            L = new [] { "typescript" },
            Suggest = new CompletionField
            {
                Input = new [] { "async", "await" },
            }
        }
    }, "autocomplete");

    client.Refresh("autocomplete");

    var searchResponse = client.Search<EO_CategoryAutocomplete>(s => s
        .Suggest(su => su
            .Completion("categories", cs => cs
                .Field(f => f.Suggest)
                .Prefix("as")
                .Contexts(co => co
                    .Context("lang", 
                        cd => cd.Context("c#"), 
                        cd => cd.Context("typescript"))
                )
            )
        )
    );

    // do something with suggestions
    var categorySuggestions = searchResponse.Suggest["categories"];
}
```

The `searchResponse` returns

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "suggest" : {
    "categories" : [
      {
        "text" : "as",
        "offset" : 0,
        "length" : 2,
        "options" : [
          {
            "text" : "async",
            "_index" : "autocomplete",
            "_type" : "eo_categoryautocomplete",
            "_id" : "3",
            "_score" : 1.0,
            "_source" : {
              "id" : "3",
              "l" : [
                "typescript"
              ],
              "suggest" : {
                "input" : [
                  "async",
                  "await"
                ]
              }
            },
            "contexts" : {
              "lang" : [
                "typescript"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "text" : "async",
            "_index" : "autocomplete",
            "_type" : "eo_categoryautocomplete",
            "_id" : "1",
            "_score" : 1.0,
            "_source" : {
              "id" : "1",
              "suggest" : {
                "input" : [
                  "async",
                  "await"
                ],
                "contexts" : {
                  "lang" : [
                    "c#"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "contexts" : {
              "lang" : [
                "c#"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

suggesting documents with ids `"1"` and `"3"`. You can also use [Source Filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) to only return the fields that you are interested in from `_source`.

Comment: no worries! You can upvote it as well if it helped :)